# Text parser gives false negative on needle when haystack contains extra markup

Tags: php, regex, parsing

The code below takes a keyword and a string of text (sanitized of html tags) and determines if the keyword appears in the last sentence of the sanitized content.

There's one glitch that I can't figure. When the end of the content contains so much as an empty space or paragraph tag with a nonbreaking space, ie

```
This is the last sentence.<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I get a false negative (no match), despite the fact that (1) The keyword is definitely in the last sentence and (2) the strip_tags() function should render the appearance of the tag at the end a non issue.

Anyone see why that might be happening?

```
function plugin_get_kw_last_sentence($post) {
    $theContent = strip_tags(strtolower($post->post_content));
    $theKeyword = 'test';
    $thePiecesByKeyword = plugin_get_chunk_keyword($theKeyword,$theContent);
    if (count($thePiecesByKeyword)>0) {
        $theCount = $thePiecesByKeyword[count($thePiecesByKeyword)-1];
        $theCount = trim($theCount,'.');
        if (substr_count($theCount,'.')>0) {
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

function plugin_get_chunk_keyword($theKeyword, $theContent) {
    if (!plugin_get_kw_in_content($theKeyword,$theContent)) {
        return array();
    }

    $myPieceReturn = preg_split('/\b' . $theKeyword . '\b/i', $theContent);
    return $myPieceReturn;
}
```

Comment: You need to double back slash those word boundaries, \\b

Comment: @Tony, thanks. Can you help me understand why?

Comment: in PHP backslashses are used to escape characters in quoted strings.  So in order to have a literal backslash in your regex, you need to escape it with another backslash.

Comment: Thanks Tony, I appreciate your explanation and your elegant solution to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a lot going on there that I think can be covered in the regex alone, if I understand your logic correctly.  Couldn't the whole logic be reduced down to this:

```
function plugin_get_kw_last_sentence($post) {
    $pattern = '/' . $theKeyword . '[^.!?]*[.!?][^.!?]*$/';
    $subject = strip_tags(strtolower($post->post_content));
    return preg_match($pattern, $subject);
}
```

The regex matches when it finds your keyword and the final sentence ending punctuation mark with no other sentence ending punctuation marks between them.

Now this is obviously not bullet proof as things like titles (i.e., Mr., Mrs.) and etc... and anything else including these sentence ending punctuation marks will throw you off.  This should get you what you're asking for, as your given code does not account for those situations either.

Comment: @Tony, sounds logical. Running it through some tests now. I suppose I could devise a workaround for the most common exceptions that you mention. Wouldn't be a bad idea actually. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Tony, I'm trying to test, but getting: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '*' (on the preg_match() line). ?

Comment: add forward slashes to open and close the regex pattern I gave you.  Check my edit in the code above.  Sorry about that.

Comment: That fixed the error message. Thanks. Problem is that your function, like mine, is still returning FALSE negs. My keyword is "test keyword" in the last sentence which is: "The test keyword is here.<p>&nbsp;</p>"

Comment: ...However, when I change the sentence to: "The test keyword is here." I get return TRUE, just like I expect.

Comment: Check the $subject.  strip_tags() is only going to remove the HTML tags, not their content.  The &nbsp; will still be at the end of the $subject.  Use the edit I made above to give a little more leeway to what can come after the last sentence ending punctuation mark.

Comment: Yep! That did it. +1 and selected. Still not sure why <p>&nbsp;</p> was considered the end of the sentence since it does not contain a period. What am I missing?

Comment: @Tony, I really like the simplicity of your function. How would you modify your regex for matching keyword in the first sentence?

Comment: '/^[^.!?]*' . $theKeyword . '[^.!?]*[.!?]/'